# Typecasting from open array parameter to TArray<>

Tags: delphi

Check the following code:

```
function A(const points: TArray<TPoint>): Boolean;
begin
   //Something
end;

procedure B(var pts: array of TPoint)
begin
   A(pts); //Compiler error E2010 Incompatible types
end;
```

It yields a compiler error:

E2010 Incompatible types: 'System.TArray' and 'array of TPoint'

Calling `A(TArray<>(pts));` doesn't work. I solve the problem doing

```
A(TArray<TPoint>(@pts));
```

**Is it the proper way to typecast an open array parameter to TArray<>? Is there any other way?**

Please assume that parameters type of both function **can not** be changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why casting an open array parameter to an array type causes E2089 Invalid typecast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50414260/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot perform such a typecast. An open array is no a dynamic array. Your options include:

1. Use a dynamic array for both procedures.
2. Use an open array for both procedures.
3. Copy the content of the open array to a dynamic array, and pass that.

Of these I would note that copying is expensive and I would reject that option on principle.

Comment: It just looks like it works. But there are some actions that will fail.